# How to use nohup to continue to run a command after the user logout?

Tags: linux, node.js, background-process, nohup, bitnami

`nohup <command> <arg> &`

When I SSH into a Linux server, if I want to run a command and make sure that it will continue to run in the background after I logout from SSH, I will use the above commands.

Recently I am using a server stack called [Bitnami Node.js stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/nodejs). It is a self-contained software bundle. There is a `node` binary in the bin folder in the installation directory.

In the command line, I am able to use the `node` command to run my JS programs: `node <js_program.js>`. There is no problem.

But, I would like to continue to run the program after I logout from SSH. When I run `nohup <installation_dir>/nodejs/bin/node <js_program.js> > <stdout.out> &`, the program will run in the background. But, when I logout from SSH, the program will also terminate immediately. It seems that the `nohup` command has no effect in this case.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you ever considered running your command via `screen` or `tmux`?

Comment: What is the output of stdout.out and nohup.out? Is it showing anything as why its terminating? I guess it would be some kind of limitation in the infrastructure as Bitnami seems to be a stack dedicated to running Node apps, so maybe you don't have a fully working OS as you are expecting (just a guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by changing the way I logout from the SSH shell terminal.

Instead of clicking the `X` button to close the PuTTY window, I type `exit` in the SSH shell terminal to logout. Now the process is able to continue to run in the background after I logout.

If I click the `X` button to close the window, the background process will terminate immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Running:

```
nohup command ... > file &
```

will leave stderr and stdin open. Instead, run:

```
nohup command ... > file 2>&1 <&- &
```

or:

```
nohup command ... > logfile 2> errfile <&- &
```

which will redirect stdout and close stdin.

Keep in mind that your command may abort if it can't read from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `at` package installed, and you're not denied (either directly via `/etc/at.deny`, or implicitly via `/etc/at.allow`) from using it, try using either of:

```
  echo "<installation_dir>/nodejs/bin/node <js_program.js> > <stdout.out>" | at now
```

or:

```
  at now
```

and specify your command at the `at>` prompt.

This should schedule the command to run immediately via the `at` daemon.

This how I've traditionally "emulated" `nohup` on systems with broken `nohup` implementations (AIX 5.3 and earlier, for example).